# Trim the returned ISO Time using Javascript in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I am retrieving the ISO time and the returned format is

```
2018-06-28T03:20:27.000Z
```

But i want it in the below format

2018-06-28T03:20:27

The milli second part should be trimmed.
I am generating time using java script in Jmeter and the snippet of it is like below,

```
var currentTime = new Date();
currentTime.setHours(currentTime.getHours());
var currentTime = new Date(currentTime).toISOString();
vars.put("currentTime",currentTime);
```

Thansk in advcance..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
currentTime = currentTime.split('.')[0]
```

Which truncates the milliseconds part

Updated code snipped

```js
        var currentTime = new Date();
        currentTime.setHours(currentTime.getHours());
        var currentTime = new Date(currentTime).toISOString();
        console.log("currentTime",currentTime);
        currentTime = currentTime.split('.')[0] 
        console.log("currentTime",currentTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the slice for trim extra part

```js
var iSOTime = (new Date(Date.now())).toISOString().slice(0, -5);
console.log(iSOTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid using JavaScript, it might become a performance bottleneck when it comes to high loads. Since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use the most performing scripting option which are [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) with Groovy language and [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function correspondingly.

The Groovy equivalent of your code would be:

```
vars.put('currentTime', new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss'))
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)